# Rails - NoMethodError in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My application has a Patient which has many requests and additionals associated with it, every time I try view my additionals for a patient I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in AdditionalsController#index

undefined method `additionals' for #<Patient:0x007fb3e7c1aaf0> Did you mean? additonals additonals=
Extracted source (around line #8):

6 @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
7 # Access all additionals for that patient
8 @additionals = @patient.additionals
9 end
10
```

patient.rb

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :requests
  has_many :additonals
  def self.search(search_for)
    Patient.where("last_name = ?", search_for)
  end
end
```

additional.rb

```
class Additional < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient
 end
```

additional_controller.rb

```
class AdditionalsController < ApplicationController
  def index


 @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    # Access all additionals for that patient
    @additionals = @patient.additionals
  end

  # GET /patients/1/additionals/2
  def show
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    # For URL like /patients/1/additionals/2
    # Find an additional in patients 1 that has id=2
    @additional = @patient.additionals.find(params[:id])
  end
  # GET /patients/1/additionals/new
  def new
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    # Associate an additional object with patient 1
    @additional = @patient.additionals.build
  end
  # POST /patients/1/additionals
  def create
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    # For URL like /patients/1/additionals
    # Populate an additional associate with patient 1 with form data
    # Patient will be associated with the additional
    # @additional = @patient.additionals.build(params.require(:additional).permit!)
    @additional = @patient.additionals.build(params.require(:additional).permit(:date, :cost, :note))
    if @additional.save
    # Save the additional successfully
      redirect_to patient_additional_url(@patient, @additional)
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  # GET /patients/1/additionals/2/edit
  def edit
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    # For URL like /patients/1/additionals/2/edit
    # Get additional id=2 for patient 1
    @additional = @patient.additionals.find(params[:id])
  end
  # PUT /patients/1/additionals/2
  def update
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @additional = Additional.find(params[:id])
    if @additional.update_attributes(params.require(:additional).permit(:date, :cost, :note))
      # Save the additional successfully
      redirect_to patient_additional_url(@patient, @additional)
    else
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end

# DELETE /patients/1/additionals/2
  def destroy
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @additional = Additional.find(params[:id])
    @additional.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to patient_additionals_path(@patient) }
      format.xml { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT - updated to show full error message.

Comment: Could you show the whole error message?

Comment: Sure, have updated now. Thanks for taking a look !

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure you read the entire error message.

It looks like you have a spelling error `additonals` (from the "Did you Mean")

Most likely you spelled your `has_many :additionals` relationship wrong.

Comment: That was the exact error, my bad sorry about that. Been staring at it too long and didn't notice! Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

In the `Patient` model you have:

```
has_many :additonals
```

It should be:

```
has_many :additionals
```

Comment: Thanks mate, really should have seen that. I've been staring at it the best part of the day and missed it. Cheers

Comment: Take a better look at an error message next time! :)